# Tar --compare over an ssh connection

Tags: ssh, compare, tar, remote-server, data-transfer

I have a lot of image data on a remote server that I need to copy over to a local drive. The local drive writes data off to tape after 30days, and so it is important that the data is kept together in convenient chunks otherwise it can end up on multiple tapes and take several days to retrieve. To do this I ssh into the remote server, tar up each image sequence into a tarball, and write it to the local drive using CPIO. The result is I have my image sequence on the remote server, and the tar file locally.

What I want to do:

Check that the tar file contains everything that it is meant to contain. I believe using the tar --compare flag is the way to go, however I am having trouble figuring out how to use --compare to compare a local tar file to the source files on a remote server via ssh.

So far I think I can run the command locally using the following:

```
# Somehow tell it the files are located across an ssh connection
tar --compare --file=test.tar -C
```

But I don't know how to do the last part.
I have an SSH key setup with the remote server so I do not need to enter a password.

Alternatively if you have another method of doing this comparison I would love to hear it.

Comment: Mount remote filesystem local with NFS, CIFS oder SSHFS and comapre locally.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus, we gave this a go, but found if something goes wrong with the remote file system it will need to be remounted, which is fine for me to do, but an extra step for not so computer savvy people. Our solution has been to create md5 files and copy these across with the tar, and compare these two locally. Thanks again for the comment!